# What does current clip mean?

Tags: android, android-canvas

The page for `Canvas` in the android developers guide refers to the "current clip" 72 times, but I can't find where it says what this actually means. Can someone explain? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current clip determines where draws to the canvas will be allowed, and where they will be ignored.

Drawing within the current clip region will be applied to the canvas, while drawing outside of the current clip region will not be applied to the canvas.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can change the current clip?

Comment: Yup.  You can call any of the various clipXXX methods on Canvas to modify the current clip region.  If you need to do various clipping operations during the same onDraw pass, you can make use of Canvas' save and restore methods to remember where you were before you applied a clip and restore it to this prior state after you are done using it.